# XStream Serialize a class to XML using an attribute field as attribute for XML tag of another field

Tags: java, xml, xstream

i have this class

```
public class EventXML{
    private String name;
    private String ip;
    private Date date;
    private String dateFormat;
    private String eventName;
}
```

using this function:

```
public String toXML(){
        String x;
        XStream xs = new XStream();
        x = xs.toXML(this);
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"+x;
    }
```

i get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EventXML>
      <name>SuperFarmer</name>
      <ip>IPPPPPPP</ip>
      <myData>2018-05-15 12:48:05.343 UTC</myData>
      <dateFormat>HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy</dateFormat>
      <eventName>CLICCA</eventName>
    </EventXML>
```

but i would like an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventXML>
  <name>SuperFarmer</name>
  <ip>IPPPPPPP</ip>
  <myData dateFormat="HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy">12:48:05 15/05/2018</myData>
  <eventName>CLICCA</eventName>
</EventXML>
```

could you give me some tips to get my objective?

Comment: so the problem is with the attribute or the date format?

Comment: both of two, but most important is use dateFromat as attribute for myData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reach the desired xml outupt with some changes to the `EventXML` class. I created an inner class that holds the `<myData>`element and attribute:

```
public class EventXML
{
    public String name;
    public String ip;
    public MyData myData = new MyData();
    public String eventName;

    public static class MyData {
        public Date date;
        public String dateFormat;
    }
}
```

now in the serialization method, we tell xstream how to serialize `MyData` into an xml element and also tell xstream how to convert date fields:

1. `ToAttributedValueConverter` accepts a class (first arg) and name of field (last arg) the named field will be used as element's value, and all other fields of the class will be used as attributes
2. `DateConverter` is used by xstream to convert `Date` typed fields I gave it `dateFormat` as argument.

this is how it looks:

```
public String toXML() {
    String x;
    XStream xs = new XStream();

    // the following tell XStream how to craete myData element:
    // the last arg is the field to be used as element value and all other fields are attributes
    xs.registerConverter(new ToAttributedValueConverter(MyData.class, xs.getMapper(), xs.getReflectionProvider(),
        xs.getConverterLookup(), "date"));
    // register date converter according to dateFormat field
    xs.registerConverter(new DateConverter(myData.dateFormat, new String[]{}));

    x = xs.toXML(this);
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"+x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Xstream 1.14.x**, use annotations.

The **EventXML** object should look like this:

```
public class EventXML {
    public String name;
    public String ip;

    @XStreamAlias("myData")
    public MyData myData = new MyData();

    public String eventName;

    @XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"date"})
    public static class MyData {

        public Date date;

        @XStreamAsAttribute
        public String dateFormat;
    }
}
```

Maven dependency (in case you use maven):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And your toXml method should look like this (with processAnnotations):

```
public String toXml() {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    // Note the processAnnotations:
    xstream.processAnnotations(EventXML.class);
    String x = xstream.toXML(this);
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + x;
}
```